# How to fix 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions' error in jsx VS Code

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have some code and it keeps giving me this error, and I can't find the reason why. Error: 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions'

I have tried to delete the return, but that doesn't work.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Search from '../users/Search';
import Users from '../users/Users';

const Home = () => {
  <Fragment>
    <Search />
    <Users />
  </Fragment>
};

export default Home
```

Comment: You need to return from the function... `return (<Fragment> ... </Fragment>)`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't fix my problem! Still the same error.

Comment: It’s exactly the same thing as the answer below :) The first is what is called an explicit return... When you have the curly braces you need the return key word... The second is what is called implicit return... No curly braces... just parentheses...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `()` around Fragments.

```
const Home = () => {
  return (<Fragment>
    <Search />
    <Users />
  </Fragment>)
};
```

OR -

```
const Home = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Search />
    <Users />
  </Fragment>
);
```